# Is spell vamp triggered by true damage?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is spell vamp triggered by abilities that do true damage?  For example, does [Nunu's](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Nunu_the_Yeti_Rider) consume heal more if he has a [Will of the Ancients](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Will_of_the_Ancients)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So spell vamp isn't about Magic/Physical/True damage, but rather about "Abilities."  The term Abilities here is meant to be distinct from "Auto-Attacks" (which benefit from life-steal).  With a few notable exceptions all attacks fall into one of these categories: Auto-Attacks or Abilities.

This means that things like: Feast and Consume benefit from spell vamp. [cite](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spell_vamp), [cite](http://forum.leaguecraft.com/index.php?/topic/36192-spell-vamp-vs-true-damage/), [cite](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1974936), [cite](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1792460)

Now it's worth noting that there is a class of abilities, "On-Hit," which are not clear as to whether they fall into the "Auto-Attack" or "Abilities" category.  Some of these will benefit from life steal (eg. Blitzcrank's  Power Fist), some will benefit from spell vamp (eg. consuming a mark from  Akali's  Mark of the Assassin), and some will benefit from neither (eg.  Irelia's  Hiten Style), though the auto-attack portion will still benefit from life steal.

A full list of these abilities can be found here: [leagueoflegends.wikia: On-Hit_effects](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/On-hit_effect)

Comment: Thanks!  I read WoTA was awesome on Nunu, but I couldn't remember if consume always healed that much.

Comment: I cannot edit "life style" => "life steal" because it says edits must be at least 6 chars long

Comment: Smite also benefits from Spell Vamp [(last bullet in "Strategy")](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Smite)